# Apache: forbidden on virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I've

```
/var/www/app.mydomain.com
```

This contain only on `index.html` with

```
<h1>I want it works ... please</h1>
```

This is my  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app-mydomain-com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  app.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin info@mydomain.it

        DocumentRoot /var/www/app.mydomain.com

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhosts/app-mydomain-com/access.log vhost_combined
        ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhosts/app-mydomain-com/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

When I open browser at app.mydomain.com I got a forbidden from apache

In the error.log (the main error.log, NOT the one specific of my vhost) I got

> Cannot serve directory /var/www/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,
>   index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

I totally have no idea of what does it mean in my case

I tried to add

```
    DirectoryIndex index.html
```

But nothing changes (after a restart of apache2, of course)

I verified that site was enabled

```
a2ensite app-mydomain-com
Site app-mydomain-com already enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the problem was only a missing `ServerAlias` directive.